# How to SendInput the following string: {\color{red} TO-DO}

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to have a hotstring in AutoHotkey such that, when I type the string `ltodo`
the following literal is printed: `{\color{red} TO-DO}`

I tried to do this in autohotkey:

```
:R*?:ltodo::
SendInput, {\color{red} TO-DO}
return
```

with no luck, as it prints the string TO-DO only.

How can I make it print the literal: `{\color{red} TO-DO}`

Answer (score 1):

```
:R*?:ltodo::{\color{red} TO-DO}
```

But if you are genuinely wanting to know how to accomplish this with Sendinput:

```
:R*?:ltodo::
Sendinput, {raw}{\color{red} TO-DO}
Return
```

The functionality of these two examples is basically identical;
because SI is the default mode for hotstrings.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
::ltodo::
SendRaw {\color{red} TO-DO}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the brackets between brackets like this.

```
 *:R*?:ltodo::send, {{}\color{{}red{}} TO-DO{}}*
```

Sorry, in combining the 3 lines to 1, I left the send command...It had to be:

```
 :R*?:ltodo::{{}\color{{}red{}} TO-DO{}}
```

Personally, I would probably use one of the following shortcodes:

```
  td/  or   td\   or even just a double \\
```